# Multiple graphics cards. Is there a way to designate one as compute device only?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, gpu

I recently bought 1070ti to be my main card and I also have old 1060 6GB model as a secondary card to aid Cycles rendering.

I am noticing that both cards read (Display) in the Blender settings. Is this optimal setting? I'm in Windows 10. Is there a way to designate my 1060 to be a compute device only, never be used for display?

Comment: Are the cards connected to different monitors?

Comment: No there is only one monitor connected to 1070ti. 1060 6GB has nothing connected.

Comment: I noticed that, in windows it makes no difference. On linux the card that is connected to the display will be labeled as (display). In any case, both cards are used for rendering if they are selected as compute device.